# Is it true that $A$ is Morita equivalent with $M_I(A)$

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, banach-algebras, morita-equivalence

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra. Is it true that $A$ is Morita equivalent with $M_I(A)$, where $I$ is an arbitrary index set ($M_I(A)$ is the space of $I*I$ matrices with entries in $A$. Let $a,b\in M_I(A)$ and $P$ be an invertible $I*I$ matrix with entries in $A$. The product of $a,b$ is defined by $a.b=aPb$).

Comment: How is $M_I(A)$ a Banach algebra if $I$ is infinite? How do you define multiplication?

Comment: It is not entirely clear, in the world of Banach algebras, what the "correct" notion of Morita equivalence should be. One possibility was investigated by Niels Gronbaek in a paper in the 1990s in JPAA (I don't have the details to hand right now)

Comment: If you are thinking of what some people like to call Munn algebras, which in turn are motivated by convolution algebras of Rees semigroups, then there was some discussion in a paper of Gourdeau, Gronbaek and White, Studia Mathematica, published between 2005 to 2010 I think?

Comment: As @QiaochuYuan has pointed out, in order for $aPb$ to be well-defined, you must specify some extra conditions on $M_I(A)$, such as convergence with respect to some norm. I have downvoted the question until this is clarified.

Comment: I did not know about other notions of Morita equivalence or the definition of the multiplication when I answered. So if necessary I will delete my answer in case it was off topic.

Comment: If P is invertible then your Munn algebra is isomorphic to a usual matrix algebras on I.

Comment: @Mare I think it is up to the OP to clarify what he means, since the question seems currently ill-posed

Comment: Let A be a unital Banach algebra, and $I$ be an
arbitrary index set, and let $M_
I (A)$ be the vector space of all $I × I$-matrices
$A=(A_i j)$ over $A$ such that $\norm A =\Sigma_i,j\in I \norm  A_i j $.
Then, it is easy to check that $M_I (A)$ with scaler multiplication, matrix
addition, and the above norm  is a Banach space. This Banach space is
called $\ell_1-Munn$ Banach space over A. If $M_I (A)$ is a Banach algebra, by product as above ($P$ be the $I*I$ matrix with $a_i j=0$ and $a_i i=1_A$), then $M_I (A)$ is called the $\ell_1-Munn$ Banach algebra over $A$ with index set I.

Comment: @fereidoun, please edit your question so that it contains the correct definition. Incidentally "$\ell_1$-Munn Banach space" is bad terminology in my view, and I wish people would not use it.

Comment: @fereidoun also, please explain to us what you meant when you said "Morita equivalence", because it was not clear from the formulation of your question where you had seen this definition and what you think it means

Comment: You have now changed the question completely, this is not fair on the previous commenters. Please ask your new question as a separate question. I am reverting this to the original version, since your original question about Morita equivalence does not seem to be directly related to your second question about being self-induced

Comment: I am so sorry about that. you are right, but as your first comment, to prove Morita equivalence of two Banach algebras, we must first prove that they are self-induced, so I guessed that the above identification must first be prove. Anyway, thank you so much for your remarks.

Answer (score 7):

Taking $A= \mathbb{C}$ , $A$ is not Morita equivalent to $B=M_I (A)$ when $I$ is infinite, since $A$ is artinian but $M_I (A)$ is not (here I assume that $M_I(A)$ is defined as the endomorphism ring of a vector space of $\mathbb{C}$ with a basis of cardinality $I$). One way to see that $B$ is not artinian is for example to note that $B \cong B^2$ as $B$-modules.
For finite $I$, and general $A$ and $M_I(A)$ are of course Morita equivalent as is well known (see for example the book "Lectures on modules and rings" chapter 17 by Lam).